# How to stop screen flicker when updating an Image control in a userform

Tags: excel, vba, image

I am trying to stop the image in a userform image control flashing when one image is overwrittem by another.

Context

I am working with images from a CCTV camera which is set up to take a still image every 10 seconds, saved as .jpg files to a specified location. The intention is to work through images and select a sub list of images which are transfered to another location for subsequent processing into a time lapse video file. The selection routine parses through the images in various ways displaying each image in a large image control on a userform. One of the means of parsing the images is a loop that writes images sequentially to the control effectively emulating the finished time lapse video.

The line of code that displays the image is:

```
            Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value & "\" & NewFil)
```

where TextBox1 contains the path to the folder containing the image files and 'NewFil' is the full name of the image file.

In general, the code is working quite well and doing everything I want it to... however...

The issue

When one image is overwritten by another, the image control often flashes with the background colour. This doesn't happen with every frame and appears to be at random intervals... On average, I would say it happens for one in every three or four image changes. Needless to say, the effect can be quite disruptive almost migraine inducing. What I want to achieve is a flicker free transition form one image to another.

Tried so far:

1. Stopping screenupdating while the image is in process of being displayed - No effect
2. Having two Image Controls sharing the smae foorprint on the form, one visible, one not and writing the image to the invisible control before toggling the controls to mahe the invisible control visible and vice versa - No effect.

I'm wondering if this is a limitation of the system and if I'll have to live with it... any suggestions?

RF

Answer (score 0):

**Switch visibility of image control off, then on.**

Hi I encountered a similar problem where the image control would 'flicker' and show the background until my mouse cursor went out of the image control and then back in. Resolved this flickering issue by turning the visibility of the image control off, then on again.
E.g. In your case:

`Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value & "\" & NewFil)`

`Me.Image1.Visible = False`

`Me.Image1.Visible = True`

Let me know if it worked.